# Why won't this angular date-picker appear and work properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to implement [this Angular Date-Picker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) in my application but it is not working.

Here is my HTML:

```
HELLO WORLD!
<div ng-controller="DatePickerCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="minDate"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp',
  [
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages'
  ]
);

myApp.controller('DatePickerCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log('Hello!');
    $scope.myDate = new Date();
    $scope.minDate = new Date(
        $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
        $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
        $scope.myDate.getDate());
  }
);
```

But it doesn't work. When I run it, I get this very odd behavior where a large black-and-white image of a stylized calendar shows up, but no actual date-picking. Take a look:

[image]

What's going on? How to fix this? 
The JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n5not3hs/5/). But it doesn't exhibit the same behavior. In the JSFiddle, I see the following error on the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: The JSFiddle is broken for me as the external resources seem to be unavailable (hence the "Unexpected Token" error)

Comment: Corvus, yes. I explicitly added the two resources (`ngMaterial` and `ngmessages`) in the left panel of the JSFiddle. I have no clue why its not finding them.

Comment: I assume that your actual application includes the relevant "dependencies" for angular-material -- including the css file?

Comment: mgilson, Hmmmm. Interesting point. I believe I have those CSS files. To install angular-material I just did `bower install angular-material`. In the directory that bower install, I do see a handful of `.css` files.

Comment: Yes Thanks. Turns out I was missing angular material's css file. I inserted the following line just before my date-picker and it worked: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably missing the angular dependencies. You require the following CDNs to get your app working. JsFiddle doesnt allow the http external source.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <style>
```

Here is the working plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/zfY0azlAhD2MjOKm16qy?p=preview

Comment: Yes Thanks. Turns out I was missing angular material's css file. I insterted the following line just before my date-picker and it worked: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">`

Comment: glad it helped you :)